# Database design approach for Official Logins and Guests

Tags: sql, database-design, authentication, normalization, data-modeling

My company sells online courses.  We add the users to a Login table.  When a user purchases a course we make an entry into the purchase table.

`UserID | CourseID | PurchaseDate`

Currently, the Purchase table has referential integrity with the Login table based on the UserID.

We are looking to add a Guest option for customers who do not want to signup.  I want to keep all of the purchases in the Purchase table.  Is there a best practice for this?

I could just add a `GuestID` to the `Purchase` table, but before I do that, I wanted to know what other people thought.

Comment: is the "Guest option" will remain always Guest or down after some trial period that user want to upgrade his guest account as full use, have you thought about such questions? or this is like generic Guest account all user can use it to login and currently there are not vision of future expansion. You can also create user as regular user login just add a Flag on Login table indicating if User is currently as "Guest user".  this is a property of Login/User not the Purchase.

Comment: They are a Gust until they decide to create a login.  It is up to them  to decide if they want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In sake of the relational integrity and business logic I can create guest users by demand and use then exactly as ordinary users.

Only things to do: create a flag IsGuest an a random name like 'guest'+guid() for that useres. For all matters they can be handled as any other user.

Maybe an advantage is the possibility to leverage a user status. Its just trivial to set the IsGuest flag and update the user's name.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind your existing system. I will create one more table say Person which will be a master table and USER will become a child table with relationship as one to one.

Now Person table will be considered as any guest with or without credentials however USER already represents person with credentials.

`Person(PersonID primary key)  -> User(UserID as primary key referencing Person.PersonID)`

So if I have to create a user who is signing up, Then I will make an entry into two tables i.e. Person then User. If a person is not siging up, then an entry will be made only to Person table.

`Purchase(PurchaseID, CourseID, PersonID as Foreign key)` which indirectly refrences User as well being one to one relationship.

eg.
[image]

Consider EntityID = PersonID in image. I used some design of my db.

In terms of OOP, I can model it as

```
Class Person
{
 int PersonID;
}

class User:Person
{
string UserName;
string Password;
}

class PurchaseOrder
{
int PurchaseOrderId;
int CourseID;
int PersonId;
}
```

What I think is this will make your system more scalable and reduce redundancy.